# User.Identity.IsAutenticated getting reset to false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have two MVC4 applications hosted on 2 virtual directories on IIS. Site B redirects to site A for authentication, gets redirected back to A.
I am trying to set AuthCookie (FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("admin",false)) at both sites. The issue is each call to set the cookie resets the User.Identity.IsAutenticated of another site. If I host these two applications on different machines, everything works alright.

1. User tries to access to Site B, gets redirected to site A for authentication
2. User gets authenticated on site A, SetAuthCookie is called (in the controller), gets redirected to site B.
3. On Site B's Application_AuthenticateRequest of Global.asax SetAuthCookie is called.
4. User tries to access Site A..Here IsAuthenticated is set to false because of step 3.

I am using different application pools as suggested on some sites, but it still doesn't work. If you could point out what's that I am doing wrong..